# Data that is saved in a Snapshot and transfer it to a double

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hi i would like to ask how can I retrieve the data from the Firestore and send it to a double.

This is the code where I get retrieve the data from Firestore.

```
Firestore.instance
            .collection('locations')
            .snapshots()
            .listen((driverLocation){
          driverLocation.documents.forEach((dLocation){
            dLocation.data['latitude'] = latitude;
            dLocation.data['longitude'] = longitude;
            print(latitude);
          });
        });
```

I store it inside the `dLocation` and when i `print(dLocation.data)` it will display the latitude and longitude in the Firestore. But when i pass it to the `double latitude` and `double longitude` it returns null.

```
busStop.add(
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('driverLocation')
            ,
            draggable: false,
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
            onTap: () {
            },
            position: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
          ));
```

Then i would like to pass the data that is in the `double latitude` and `double longitude` into the marker so that the marker will move accordingly to the latitude and longitude in the Firestore.

Everything that is happening here is in a `initState()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have reversed the assignment

```
 Firestore.instance
                .collection('locations')
                .snapshots()
                .listen((driverLocation){
              driverLocation.documents.forEach((dLocation){
                latitude = dLocation.data['latitude'] ;
                longitude = dLocation.data['longitude']  ;
                print(latitude);
              });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('locations')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((driverLocation) {
       driverLocation.documents.forEach((dLocation){
         var latitude = dLocation.data['latitude'];
         var longitude = dLocation.data['longitude'];
         print('latitude: $latitude, longitude: $longitude');
      });
   });
```

Comment: same return back null in the latitude and longitude